# Find the subset of an array such that the elements in the subset have a common difference

Tags: arrays, subset, difference

I came across a question while preparing for my interview.
Given an array of integers as input.
We have find a possible subset such that the elements in the array have a common difference.
For example,
Consider the input array to be {1,3,7,10,11}
Then the output should be {3,7,11}.
It is always that the elements in the array are in increasing order.
I thought of finding all the subsets and look for a solution.
But that would cause my program to run slower if the input array size is too large.
can anyone help me to crack this???

Comment: your problem is not well formed: does it have to be one the largest subset? because the set of only the first element is always a subset of constant differences.

Comment: yes the largest subset...

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to extract possible subsets from an array such that each two consecutive numbers have the same difference value increasingly.

Here is my algorithm:

1. Remove duplicates.
2. Force arrange ascendingly.
3. Keep a hashtable with the difference values as keys and lists of lists as values.
4. Loop through the array, updating/adding a key in the hashtable that equals the difference between the two consecutive numbers at hand, and adding a list to the value (the list of lists) containing the two numbers.
5. After the loop, create an array. Loop through the hashtable, adding an element each time to the array which is an array itself: The merging of all nested lists in the value at hand.  This is the array containing all possible subsets.

Here's a possible implementation in python:

```
from itertools import chain
def find_subsets (array):
    table = dict()
    last = array[-1]
    for num in sorted (set (array), False)[1:]:
        diff = last - num
        table[diff].append([num, last])
        last = num
    return [list(chain(v)) for k, v in table]
```

Please try this code and correct it if wrong. I wrote this in a hurry.